Handling Async Image Loading in Notification Customization
I’m using Salesforce Marketing Cloud and have set up a custom notification using the MarketingCloudConfig builder. In the setupNotificationBuilder method, I’m loading an image asynchronously, but the image doesn’t get attached to the notification because the builder returns before the image is fully loaded. I want to avoid network requests on the main thread. Here's the relevant code:
MarketingCloudConfig marketingCloudConfig = MarketingCloudConfig
      .builder()
      .setApplicationId(appid)
      .setAccessToken(accesstoken)
      .setSenderId(senderid)
      .setMarketingCloudServerUrl(marketingcloudserverurl)
      .setMid(mid)
      .setAnalyticsEnabled(analytics)
      .setPiAnalyticsEnabled(etanalytics)
      .setGeofencingEnabled(location)
      .setProximityEnabled(location)
      .setNotificationCustomizationOptions(
        NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(
          new NotificationManager.NotificationBuilder() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public NotificationCompat.Builder setupNotificationBuilder(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull NotificationMessage notificationMessage) {
              int requestCode = new Random().nextInt();
              String urlString = notificationMessage.url();
              Uri uri = null;
              if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(urlString)) {
                uri = Uri.parse(urlString);
              }
              Intent intent = new Intent(context, HostActivityClass);
              intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              if (uri != null) {
                intent.setData(uri);
              }
              NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NotificationManager.createDefaultNotificationChannel(context))
                .setContentTitle(notificationMessage.title())
                .setContentText(notificationMessage.alert())
                .setSmallIcon(notificationIcon)
                .setColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.getResources(), notificationIconColor, null))
                .setContentIntent(
                  NotificationManager.redirectIntentForAnalytics(context,
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                      context,
                      requestCode,
                      intent,
                      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                    ),
                    notificationMessage,
                    true
                  )
                )
                .setAutoCancel(true);
              URL imageUrl = notificationImageUrl(notificationMessage);
              if (imageUrl != null) {
                loadImageAsync(imageUrl).thenAccept(image -> {
                  if (image != null) {
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
                      builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(image));
                    });
                  }
                });
              }
              return builder;
            }
          }
        )
      )
      .build(context);

Since the image loading is asynchronous, the notification builder returns before the image is attached. How can I ensure the image is correctly set in the notification once it’s loaded, without blocking the main thread?
Alternatively, is there a way to set the notification color through Simplified Customization options instead of using the full NotificationCustomizationOptions approach? This would simplify the setup.
Thanks for any advice!
